# Send-RDUserMessage wants a <Int32>

Tags: powershell, terminal-services

I am trying to write a short script who send a message to all the user that are currently using a particular App published

```
Get-RDUserSession -ConnectionBroker 'fqdn' | where {$_.username -eq 'user'} | 
Send-RDUserMessage HostServer $_.HostServer -UnifiedSessionId `
$_.UnifiedSessionID -MessageTitle 'Test' -MessageBody "Test. Thank you. ICT dept"
```

The Error Message:

> UnifiedSessionId Property   System.Nullable[uint32] UnifiedSessionId
>   {get;}

While Send-RDusermessage wants a Int32.
How did you guys solve this mismatch problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are having **NULL** for UnifiedSessionId. Try to do it step by step to investigate what are you getting through pipes.

Comment: Not sure why but if break it into two, holding the sessions into a variable it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-RDUserSession -ConnectionBroker 'SERVERFQDN' | where {$_.username -eq "$user"} | Send-RDUserMessage -HostServer {$_.HostServer} -UnifiedSessionId {$_.UnifiedSessionId} -MessageTitle 'Test' -MessageBody "Test. Thank you. IT dept"
```

Those items in second part needed to be in brackets to work.